# kdeconnect: can't browse files

Tags: 16.04, kde-connect

I installed `kdeconnect` and `indicator-kdeconnect` as explained at [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/easy-way-connect-android-to-ubuntu-pc) and [github](https://github.com/vikoadi/indicator-kdeconnect/issues/43):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:varlesh-l/indicator-kdeconnect
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kdeconnect indicator-kdeconnect
```

Everything seems to work properly except the ***Browse device*** functionality. If I click on the indicator and then on *Browse device*, `nautilus` pops-up however the directory (`$HOME/.config/kdeconnect/[DEVICEID]/kdeconnect_sftp/[DEVICEID]`) is empty.

Do you have any suggestion on how to proceed from here?

Thanks in advance.

## Environment

---

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

## Package Version

---

**dbus**

```
$ apt show dbus
Version: 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3
```

**kdeconnect**

```
$ apt show kdeconnect
Version: 1.0.3ubuntu16.04
```

**indicator-kdeconnect**

```
$ apt show indicator-kdeconnect
Version: 0.6ubuntu16.04.1
```

## Syslog

---

```
org.kde.kdeconnect[12766]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: Mount device: "google"
org.kde.kdeconnect[12766]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: Created mounter
org.kde.kdeconnect[12766]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: Unmount QObject(0x0)
org.kde.kdeconnect[12766]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: Starting process:  "sshfs kdeconnect@192.168.1.3:/ /home/ncrfgs/.config/kdeconnect/28cebede2fc57937/kdeconnect_sftp/28cebede2fc57937 -p 1739 -f -F /dev/null -o IdentityFile=/home/ncrfgs/.config/kdeconnect/privateKey.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-dss -o password_stdin"
org.kde.kdeconnect[12766]: QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal SftpPlugin::packageReceived(NetworkPackage): Unregistered input type in parameter list: NetworkPackage
org.kde.kdeconnect[12766]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: Process started
org.kde.kdeconnect[12766]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: "google" "Remote filesystem mounted at /home/[USER]/.config/kdeconnect/[DEVICEID]/kdeconnect_sftp/[DEVICEID]"
org.kde.kdeconnect[12766]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: stdout: "fuse: bad mount point `/home/[USER]/.config/kdeconnect/[DEVICEID]/kdeconnect_sftp/[DEVICEID]': Transport endpoint is not connected\n"
org.kde.kdeconnect[12766]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: Process finished (exit code:  1 )
org.kde.kdeconnect[12766]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: "google" Remote filesystem unmounted
org.kde.kdeconnect[12766]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: Unmount KProcess(0x1d92650)
org.kde.kdeconnect[12766]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: Destroy mounter
```

Comment: I switched to GSConnect and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer on another query, so take no credit.
When Nautilus finds the empty file you need to go to the address bar where the full address should be shown (you may need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to get the full display rather than the short one).

It will look something like:

```
/home/user/.config/kdeconnect/9e835c92cb5a86f8/kdeconnect_sftp/9e835c92cb5a86f8
```

Simply append `/sdcard` to the end of the address and nautilus should find the phone contents. Depending on your android phone and version you may have to try `/storage` or `/mnt` instead of `/sdcard`.

Comment: on newer androids you might alao need o expose the folders you want to share. since android will ask for permissions on each and no loger easily grants access to the whole /sdcard/